# tomcat server starting error?

Tags: linux, installation, tomcat6

```
1.  cd /home/mpatil/Downloads/
2. tar zxvf apache-tomcat-6.0.37.tar.gz
3. cd apache-tomcat-6.0.37/bin
4. ./startup.sh 
5. tail -f /home/mpatil/Downloads/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/logs/catalina.out
```

The command `5` results in:

```
[root@localhost bin]# tail -f /home/mpatil/Downloads/apachetomcat6.0.37/logs/catalina.out
Nov 08, 2013 12:04:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory docs
Nov 08, 2013 12:04:04 PM org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol start
INFO: Starting Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-8080
Nov 08, 2013 12:04:04 PM org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket init
INFO: JK: ajp13 listening on /0.0.0.0:8009
Nov 08, 2013 12:04:04 PM org.apache.jk.server.JkMain start
INFO: Jk running ID=0 time=0/115  config=null
Nov 08, 2013 12:04:04 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3036 ms
```

After these commands, I tried `http://locahost:8080/` in my browser but got no response. [screenshot of localhost][1]

Is there anything wrong with the commands or did I do anything wrong? I hope any one would help me & please suggest me and resolve my problem

Comment: Looks like the screenshot is missing.  Is it just a screenshot of a blank browser window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean `http://locahost:8080/` not `http://localhost:8080/` ( Note the missing "l")

If not then I would check that the process is still running

ps -ef |grep tomcat

if it is then maybe check that it is listening

netstat -lnp |grep java

Netstat params are -l: show listening ports, -n: don't resolve IP and port numbers and -p: show the processes associated with that port. ( This will need to be run as root to work )

Alternatively

lsof -p  -n

-p: Only show for one PID, PID of tomcat from the ps above, and -n for don't resolve numbers to names again.